# How can you retrieve this Laravel Collection?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

With Laravel, I have this kind of structure in a json db column :

```
[
  {
    "shift": "2",
    "users[]": [
      "2657"
    ],
    "products[]": [
      "SKU1"
    ],
    "users_categories[]": [
      "CATEGORY1"
    ],
    "products_categories[]": [
      "13"
    ]
  },
  {
    "shift": "4",
    "users[]": [],
    "products[]": [],
    "users_categories[]": [
      "CATEGORY1",
      "CATEGORY2",
      "CATEGORY3",
      "CATEGORY4"
    ],
    "products_categories[]": []
  }
]
```

How can you retrieve the good shift I try to match with users I use this code but in it's not working :( :

```
$data->whereIn('users', [2657])
```

Any ideas ? I would like to matching with products and users_categories too :)

Answer (score 0):

i think you need collection:

```
$model = Model::find(1);
$data = collect(json_decode($model->json_column));
dd($data->whereIn('users[]', [2657]));
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks it's exactly what I'm doing and this does not give any result :

```
$data->whereIn('users[]', [2657])
```